# Return SharePoint List GUID from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

The following code works to get the a list GUID by Title. What I cannot figure out is how to get the code to return that value so it can be assigned to a variable.

I am fairly new to JavaScript so the nuances trouble me. I understand most of what is going on in the code.  I added the `alert()` in the success function however, I cannot figure out where to put the return statement to get the GUID value back.

```
var list;

    function getListId(listTitle) {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        context.load(list, 'Id');

        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,success), Function.createDelegate(this,error));

    }

    function success() {
        var listId = list.get_id();
        // console.log(listId);
        alert(listId);
        return listId;
    }

    function error(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is asynchronous, so you can't "return" it in the sense you seem to be talking about. What you would normally do, however, is execute the code you need to execute for handling the `listId` from within your `success` function:

```
var list;

function getListId(listTitle) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    context.load(list, 'Id');

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,success), Function.createDelegate(this,error));

}

function success() {
    var listId = list.get_id();
    // console.log(listId);
    alert(listId);
    handleListId(listId);
}

function error(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function handleListId(listId) {
    //DO STUFF WITH YOUR listId HERE...
}
```

Comment: You can also just handle it straight in that `success` function without creating another one.